# Construct Tuple of Lists with for loop

Tags: python, tuples

I have a question about python.
I have a function that takes as input a set of 3D points.
Typically, if I do something like this, it works fine:

```
MyPoints=([0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2])
myfunction(MyPoints)
```

The problem is that I would like to generate the tuple "MyPoints" "dynamically" (i.e. with a for loop). For example:

```
MyPoints=([0,0,0])
for k in range(1,11)
     MyPoints=MyPoints+tuple([k,k,k])
myfunction(MyPoints)
```

The problem is that the code above sends me an error when I call the function. It tells me that I have "too many arguments".

So my question is simple: how can I construct a tuple of the form:
MyPoints=([0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]) (etc.)

using a for loop?

Thank you in advance for your help and time.

EDit:
Thanks for all the response, but I actuallz nothing works but it my fault. Really sorry. The onlz szntax accepted is the following:

```
myfunction(((0,0,0),),((1,1,1),),((2,2,2),),((3,3,3),)))
```

Does anyone know how to build such a structure using a loop?
Thanks again and sorry for the confusion!

Best,
Julia

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the list into a tuple when you actually intend to create a singleton tuple containing the list:

What you're doing:

```
>>> tuple([1,1,1])
(1, 1, 1)
```

What you want:

```
>>> ([1,1,1],)
([1, 1, 1],)
```

---

```
mypoints=([0,0,0],) # notice the ,
...
mypoints = mypoints + ([k,k,k],)
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks also for your response! But unfortunately it is not working either. If I use your solution to generate the list, the function tells me I have too many input arguments. If I just do myPoints=([0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]) however the function accepts the input. It is a super specific function from the ABAQUS software to interface with Python, so I don't know if the issue is from there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a list comprehension to make a list of points:

```
myPoints=[((i,i,i),) for i in range(4)]
```

If you want it as a tuple:

```
myPoints=tuple([((i,i,i),) for i in range(4)])
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response! But unfortunately it is not working. If I use: myPoints=[[i,i,i] for i in range(4)] the function tells me I have too many input arguments. If I just do myPoints=([0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]) however it works. It is a super specific function (from the ABAQUS software to interface with Python)

Comment: Could you show me just the function definition? i.e. def myFunc(x,y):

Comment: It could be that the function is unpacking the points. If this is a case, you'll see a * before the points argument. Try calling myfunction((MyPoints))

Comment: sorry I made a mistake indeed. I just edited my first post.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will helpful:

```
>>> import random
>>> a = tuple([random.choice([i for i in range(1,11)]) for j in range(3)] for v in range(3))
>>> a
([10, 5, 4], [4, 6, 6], [10, 4, 6])
```

Comment: Hello and thank you! Unfortunatelz, as for the above the function tells me I have too many input arguments when I use your method. I don't know why...

Comment: Please give me your function

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat unrelated (Moses answer is technically the right one), but you should actually use a list of tuples, not a tuple of lists.

A tuple is an heterogenous collection of fixed size where position is significant (the position of each item has a given meaning). Canonical examples are points (like in your example where  `point[0]` is the `x` coordinate, `point[1]` the `y` and `point[2]` the `z`), csv files or relational databases rows (well tabular data in general) etc. You can actually consider a tuple as a dict where keys are integers only...

A list is an homogeneous collection of variable size where position has no significance. Canonical examples would be a set of points, a set of tabular data (ie all rows from a csv file or all rows from a relational database query) etc.

In your code, you have "a set of 3D points", so "set" => `list'`, `3D point` => `tuple`.

As a bonus, building a list of tuples is way faster than building a tuple of lists (python 2.7.6):

```
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ cat pointlist.py
def test1(max=100):
    points = ()
    for i in xrange(1, max):
        points += ([i, i, i],)
    return points


def test2(max=100):
    points = []
    for i in xrange(1, max):
        points.append((i, i, i))
    return points

def test3(max=100):
    points = [(i, i, i) for i in xrange(1, max)]
    return points

import timeit

for i in (1, 2, 3):
    fun = "test%s" % i
    print "%s : " % fun
    print timeit.timeit("fun()", "from __main__ import %s as fun" % fun, number=10000)
    print

bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ python pointlist.py
test1 : 
0.0343580245972

test2 : 
0.0103368759155

test3 : 
0.00669503211975
```